# How to remove square brackets and any text inside?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a document containing some text inside square brackets, e.g.:

```
The fish [ate] the bird.
[This is some] text.
Here is a number [1001] and another [1201].
```

I need to delete all of the information contained inside the square brack and the brakets, e.g.:

```
The fish  the bird.
 text.
Here is a number  and another .
```

- I tried `sed -r 's/\[[+]\]//g' file.txt`, but this did not work.

How can I delete anything in the pattern `[<anything>]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this sed line:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "The fish [ate] the bird.
[This is some] text.
Here is a number [1001] and another [1201]."|sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g' 
The fish  the bird.
 text.
Here is a number  and another .
```

explanation:

the regex is actually straightforward:

```
\[     #match [
[^]]*  #match any non "]" chars
\]     #match ]
```

so it is

match string, starting with `[` then all chars but `]` and ending with `]`

Comment: Kent. thnx for the exp. :)

Answer (score -1):

sed 's/([^])*)/*replacement text*/g' in case of Parenthesis ()