# Removing image and link tags in markdown (md) file using bash, preferably sed, command

Tags: html, bash, shell, sed, github-flavored-markdown

I have markdown (md) files, on a git wiki, that I am changing to html. I don't want to include the images and links in the html file. Our images in markdown looks like this:

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
```

Where as our markdown links looks like:

```
[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)
```

The only real different is the '!' character. I am writing a shell script to do everything. What is a bash command(s) to remove the entire image and link tag? Here is a more basic sed stack question:

[How to remove square brackets and any text inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522855/how-to-remove-square-brackets-and-any-text-inside)

ps. can you include a smile in your answer? I am tired and want to go home.

Comment: Yow want to remove the entire line "[I'm an inline-style link](_https://www.google.com)" or text in sqaure brackets

Comment: Ideally, not the entire line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should remove them both:

```
$ sed 's/\!\{0,1\}\[[^]]*\]([^)]*)//g' file.md
```

This works too but... see potong's comment here below:

```
$ sed 's/!\?\[.*\](.*)//g' file.md
```

Comment: `echo '![123](foo)' | sed 's/\!\{0,1\}\[[^]]*\]([^)]*)//g'` works! Thanks heaps!

Comment: The second solution might remove more than you want as it uses `.*` and this is greedy. For instance if two links exist on the same line separated by text, the text will also be removed.