# Bulk removing link tags in markdown (md) files, recursively, using bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, markdown

I have some markdown files (*.md) in a directory and its subdirectories. I want to remove all link tags and only keep their anchor texts. I don't want to remove image tags.

So I have a text like

```
a text containing [a link](https://example.com) and an image
![](image.jpg)
```

I want to turn it to :

```
a text containing a link and an image
![](image.jpg)
```

I wanted to try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356408/removing-image-and-link-tags-in-markdown-md-file-using-bash-preferably-sed-c) but it removes images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`, following would work:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -E 's/(^|[^!])\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/\1\2/g'
```

If `Perl` is available, please try something like:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pe 's/(?<!!)\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/$1/g' -i
```

The fragment `(?<!!)` in the regex is a `negative lookbehind` and
it prevents the regex from matching a substring preceded by `!`.